# Might have deleted kernel, but haven't shut off computer yet

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

My /boot was full and I couldn't update, so I tried to get rid of unnecessary files, but I think I might have deleted some things I shouldn't have. I don't know if grub or grub2 works, or whether or not I can still boot into windows. However, I haven't shut off my computer yet so I was hoping I could fix everything now. What can I do?

I used this command:

> for akernel in $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/(.*)-([^0-9]+)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* ([^ ]*).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'); do sudo apt-get purge $akernel; done

uname -r

> 3.13.0-66-generic

ls -lhA /boot

> total 29M
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Oct  7 12:34 abi-3.13.0-66-generic
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 162K Oct  7 12:34 config-3.13.0-66-generic
>
> drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 1.0K Dec 17 21:41 grub
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  19M Oct 30 18:15 initrd.img-3.13.0-66-generic
>
> drwx------ 2 root root  12K Feb  7  2015    lost+found
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 174K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 175K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
>
> -rw------- 1 root root 3.3M Oct  7 12:34 System.map-3.13.0-66-generic
>
> -rw------- 1 root root 5.6M Oct  7 12:34 vmlinuz-3.13.0-66-generic

du -h /boot

> du: cannot read directory ‘/boot/lost+found’: Permission denied
>
> 12K   /boot/lost+found
>
> 2.1M  /boot/grub/i386-pc
>
> 9.0K  /boot/grub/locale
>
> 2.3M  /boot/grub/fonts
>
> 6.7M  /boot/grub 36M  /boot

df -h /boot

> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/sda3       361M  180M  159M  54% /boot

Comment: You could try to install it again. Kernels are available through `apt-get`. What's your version ?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I type uname -r, I get 3.13.0-66-generic. I don't know what that actually means

Comment: OK, `14.04` is trusty , so just run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic-lts-trusty`.

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic  
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

...where for

```
/dev/sdX
```

substitute the drive where your GRUB bootloader is installed. Normally users should **not** include a partition number, which would produce an error message as the command would attempt to write the information to a partition. You can find the Device name of this drive using the Disks application. Check twice in Disks to make sure that you type the correct Device name of the drive where your GRUB bootloader is installed.

Since it isn't done during execution of the `sudo grub-install` command, running `sudo update-grub` after the install will ensure that the GRUB menu is up-to-date.