# Might have deleted kernel - where do I install grub?

Tags: boot, kernel

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I might have deleted the Kernel whilst trying to delete 10GB of old kernels.  I haven't switched the PC off yet.

@Karel suggests an answer in a virtually identical question: [Might have deleted kernel, but haven't shut off computer yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710732/might-have-deleted-kernel-but-havent-shut-off-computer-yet) but it is vague on how to find grub (boot menu) device.  I don't have enough reputation to comment there.

His answer:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic  
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

Disks program shows that, I have one SSD (device sda), split thus:

```
|             | Extended Partition |             |
|             |     Partition 3    |             |
| Filesystem  |        129GB       |  Filesystem |
| Partition 1 |____________________| Partition 2 |
| 25GB EXT4   |     Filesystem     |  102GB FAT  |
|             |     Partition 5    |             |
|             |     129GB EXT4     |             |
```

The 25GB is Linux (bootable); the 129GB is Linux and the 102GB is W95 FAT32

So I'm guessing that I need to replace the middle command with either `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` or `sudo grub-install /dev/sda1`  When @Karel suggests to enter the device name, I don't know if he means me to include the partition number.

Comment: Disks should show you the name of the drive device file - this is the key information missing from your question - is it `/dev/sda` or something else?

Comment: Thanks @Zanna.  Yes, they are all `sda`.  You mean as opposed to `dev/sdb` `dev/sdc` etc.?

Comment: @Zanna, that might have sounded like I understood an answer .  Do you mean that I type `grub-install /dev/sda` or does it need to have the partition number (presumably `1`) as well?  I really want to get this right... I'm swimming beyond my depth and I need to not kill my install.   8^o

Comment: You install grub to the whole drive, not the partition, so you would not use the partition number

Comment: Answered!  Thanks so much for your time and knowledge, @Zanna.  I would never have thought that it was installed to more than one partition.

Comment: No worries :) hope you resolved the scary situation

Comment: Yes; bravery is now returning!  For reference if anyone else needs to do the same as me, I'm now installing apparently missing linux-headers-3.13.0-116-generic before completing the grub-install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Might have deleted kernel, but haven't shut off computer yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710732/might-have-deleted-kernel-but-havent-shut-off-computer-yet)